# How do I Understand correlated queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I just started an sql exercise-style tutorial BUT I still haven't grasped the concept of correlated queries.
name, area and continent are fields on a table.

The query is to Find the largest country (by area) in each continent, show the continent, the name and the area.

The draft work so far:

```
SELECT continent, name, population FROM world x
WHERE area >= ALL
(SELECT area FROM world y
WHERE y.continent=x.continent
AND population>0)
```

Tried reading up on  it on a few other blogs.
need to understand the logic  behind correlated queries.

Comment: With the information given, how do you think we can help you???  At least post the query which you haven't grasped.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the query you posted work.  You just need clarification of what it does.

```
SELECT continent, name, population 
FROM world x
WHERE area >= ALL (
    SELECT area FROM world y
    WHERE y.continent=x.continent
    AND population>0
)
```

The query translates to 
`"Get the continent, name, and population of a country where area is bigger than or equal to all other countries in the same continent"`.
The `WHERE` clause in the inner query is to link the 2 queries (in this case countries in the same continent).  Without the `WHERE`, it will get the country with the largest are in the world.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a correlated subquery as a looping mechanism.  This is not necessarily how it is implemented, but it describes what it does.

Consider data such as:

```
row    continent    area     population
  1        a        100          19
  2        a        200          10
  3        a        300          20
  4        b         15        2000
```

The outer query loops through each row.  Then it looks at all matching rows.  So, it takes record 1:

```
row    continent    area     population
  1        a        100          19
```

It then runs the subquery:

```
(SELECT w2.area
 FROM world w2
 WHERE w2.continent = w.continent AND
       w2.population > 0
)
```

And substitutes in the values from the outer table:

```
(SELECT w2.area
 FROM world w2
 WHERE w2.continent = 'a' AND
       w2.population > 0
)
```

This returns the set `(100, 200, 300)`.

Then it applies the condition:

```
where w1.area >= all (100, 200, 300)
```

(This isn't really valid SQL but it conveys the idea.)

Well, we know that w1.area = 100, so this condition is false.

The process is then repeated for each of the rows.  For the "a" continent, the only row that meets the condition is the third one -- the one with the largest area.